# Mobile App using Phone Gap

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to build a mobile APP using phone Gap. I have few concerns regarding phone gap.
I am just trying to convert my website to mobile app where simply i would be using the same database which is MYSQL. Earlier website was not converted into HTML5 and hence we were getting some problem at responsive end. Now i want to create a HTML5 mobile app for my mobile users and i want to build it in phone gap. Because ultimately it is a framework to build app using HTML5 and JAVASCRIPT.

How phone gap works is : we install phone gap and then install platform (android, ios etc).
according to this selection cordova.js is placed into our development environment.

```
does it mean i am making an Android App?.

isn't their any option where we can develop for common platform ?
 or in simple a common cordova.js file.
```

I don't want to publish or put this to phonegap build . just trying to make a simple website mobile app using phone gap. I am a website developer and trying to do this mobile development stuff for first time. Phonegap is really a good platform for mobile development
that's why i want to go with it. Can i accomplish things i mentioned above.

My main concern  is if i don't want to publish it and want to simply make a mobile app using HTML5 and JS . so can't we use a common cordova.js ? i don't know i am talking non sense. Any help to put me right path would be appreciated.

thanks,

cheers

**update**:

i think some are getting me wrong there. I have a website and i want to convert it for my mobile user's . So idea is to convert a website for mobile phone or handheld devices. I want to use Html5 and phonegap is a platform to build html5 app using javascript. I know building things in phonegap is not an easy job , from setting environment to build app is not an easy task. So before going ahead i want to make sure that i am on the right path. So i am not making any android or ios app . just converting a website for handheld devices and i choosed phone gap platform.

Comment: In my opinion (and it's just an opinion), other than the nifty purpose of developing your first app, I don't see why you don't just run the app as a webpage from the phone's browser. If it already works as it is, why make an app out of it? At least right now, you don't need to worry about the platform...

Comment: i am getting confused if i am going with phone gap . For startup it require platform and suppose if it is android. Does it gonna work for other platform? I am confused here. talking non sense

Comment: The point of using Phonegap is that it will compile for both Android and iOS.  But nothing is ever as simple as it seems.  You still have to do a lot of work.  What I'm saying is, if it's already a web app, it should already work on both, through the browser.  So what's the point in converting it?

Comment: What I understand is you need a mobile web app, since existing is not working on mobile web browser ? Something you can access from browser on a handheld device ?

Comment: @SachinThapa yup you got me. I need a mobile web app and i am thinking to build it in phone gap. Things are not easy from setting up environment and then building things in Phonegap. So before going ahead i want to make sure i have choosen right platform. this is the only concern

Comment: @Creator - How big is the app ? How many pages ? Accordingly I can make suggestions also how frequent are changes ? Are there any budget constraints ? if you can provide these inputs i will then answer your question base on my best knowledge.

Comment: @SachinThapa well it's a small website , to hire a maid , we have plan's for them , user can select it accordingly and pay the plan amount . So functionality and pages are not that big. But somehow it was not build in html5 so responsive thing is not coming nicely. Now client want to make mobile web app so that handheld device users can use the same. Site is build in core php using mysql db. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes this was asked a year back by me . Looks like i was talking some non sense . :D . Anyways .
  for beginners if you have same question or confusion i had above . then the answer is :

Phonegap and cordova are the hybrid approach to build cross platform app . because they just create a build means we can use any HTML5 framework or web app and then build them .But yes you should follow their format if you are building them out , Like in **www** folder put your whole code.

Now lets look at my confusion my intention was to create a mobile web app , a responsive site . If today you want to do this we have some really good html5 frameworks . [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)  Is one of them . You can use this for creating HTML5 app , don't build it , who cares we just want components that can be used for making a responsive mobile web app . HTML5 , twitter bootstrap and CSS3 are your companion to build a mobile web app .

If you need a build and want an android or ios app then use phongap or cordova to wrap your code into build.

Thanks for your patience .

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

You can develop PhoneGap application in Android platform and still you can build the apps for other platforms.

You can creates apps using 1 particular platform (Andorid, iOS, Blackberry, WP & etc) and still you can generate the apps for other platforms too.

You can generate apps for other platform either locally or using PhoneGap online services.

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong. I have a website and i want to convert it for my mobile user's . So idea is to convert a website for mobile phone or handheld devices. I want to use Html5 and phonegap is a platform to build html5 app using javascript. I know building things in phonegap is not an easy job , from  setting environment to build app is not an easy task. So before going ahead i want to make sure that i am on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Based on inputs, I would suggest following:

Migrate existing app to HTML5 and CSS3. HTML5 introduces elements and attributes that reflect typical usage on modern websites, good news is it is backward compatible.

And there is not much effort in converting it here are some of the useful links:
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp), 
[First steps in the Transition Process for HTML5](http://mrbool.com/first-steps-in-the-transition-process-for-html5/26511)

Once you are on HTML5, would recommend looking at Responsive Web Design to optimize website further for Web and Mobile and various type of devices.

Here are some links:
[Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), [Beginners Guide to RWD](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)

Cheers !!